# Getting arguments from code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if this is a bit vague, or already been asked, but I wasn't sure of the terminology so I couldn't google it. What I'm looking for is how to assign the arguments that `psutil.virtual_memory()` gives to different variables.
For example, calling `psutil.virtual_memory()` gives `(total=8374149120L, available=1247768576L, percent=85.1, used=8246628352L, free=127520768L, active=3208777728, inactive=1133408256, buffers=342413312L, cached=777834496)`

I only want to get the `percent` value, and assign it to a variable. How can I so this?

Documentation: https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) (called `vrem`) so use `percent = psutil.virtual_memory().percent`

```
>>> help(psutil.virtual_memory)
Help on function virtual_memory in module psutil:

virtual_memory()
    Return statistics about system memory usage as a namedtuple
    including the following fields, expressed in bytes:
```